# Система непредвиденных ошибок discord py

Tags: python, discord.py

Мне нужно реализовать систему непредвиденных ошибок в боте.

Конечно я знаю про:

```
@bot.event
async def on_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error):
        #тут что то будет
```

Однако мне нужно чтоб он реагировал именно на все непредвиденные в функции ошибки а не на какую то определённую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В списке событий нет события `on_error`, но есть [`on_command_error`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=on_command_error#discord.discord.ext.commands.on_command_error)

В Python `isinstance` используется, чтобы определить является ли объект экземпляром какого-либо класса, например `isinstance('test', str)`.

Чтобы проверить, является ли объект ошибки `error` какой-то конкретной ошибкой, можно воспользоваться `isinstance(error, discord.ext.commands.MissingPermissions)` и проверить, является ли `error` экземпляром класса `discord.ext.commands.MissingPermissions`.

Если вам нужно обрабатывать вообще все ошибки, то есть ли смысл использовать `isinstance`? Нет.

```py
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    print(f'Ошибка {type(error).__name__}: {error}')
```

Comment: Удивляюсь что настолько просто можно было всё сделать.